# MySQL regexp in check constraint

Tags: python, mysql, regex, constraints

This code works (I'm running it from python):

```
create table if not exists t (
    f varchar(100),
    constraint C1 check(f regexp'^1*$')
);

insert into t values ('1');

select
f,
case when f regexp '^1{0,}$' then 1 else 0 end as flg
from t;
```

The insert worked out correctly.
The last query returns row ('1', 1). That means string '1' satisfies `'^1{0,}$'`.
But if I replace regexp in creating table script from `'^1*$'` to `'^1{0,}$'` the insert will fail with "SQLInterfaceError: Check constraint 'C1' is violated" (although both regexps are equivalent).

This code fails:

```
drop table if exists t;

create table if not exists t (
    f varchar(100),
    constraint C1 check(f regexp'^1*$')
);

insert into t values ('1');
```

Thanks to commentators:
If you run this code on online-resources [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jJhVFtaZor8L2fYWdwPNej/0), it works. But it does not work on my database, which I deployed yourself (version=8.0).

Comment: The only code that fails for me is `drop t if exists;` (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f8f13). Also, what's the exact objective of the constraint? You didn't explain the problem you're trying to solve, just some code that apparently doesn't work. Should the constraint check for the character `'1'` and only `'1'`?

Comment: Also works for me in MySQL 8.0: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jJhVFtaZor8L2fYWdwPNej/0

Comment: I fixed drop query, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your working examples. So it makes more strange that your examples are working but mine not. Im using MySQL version=8.0.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I'm running sql-scripts from python and I used f-string `f"{}"`, where curly braces are special symbols. So it needs to stop using f-string for this query.

Comment: I added info about python in the description and as a tag. But tell me if I need to delete this question.